# Get the last value in a macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I create a macro variable
   `%let param1 = 201601 201602 201603 201604 201605;` 
I don't know how to get the last value of that variable and assign it to a new variable. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%let last = %scan(&param1, -1) ;
```

When the second argument is negative, it scans from the right instead of left.